# converting to date format

Tags: excel, date, format

I have the following data:

```
Start Date  End Date    Week             Month
02/01/2019  03/01/2019  Week: 3467-1    3467-67
02/01/2019  03/01/2019  Week: 3467-1    3467-67
```

I used the following formulas to get the WEEK & MONTH:

```
WEEK: ="Week: "&RIGHT(B3,4)&"-"&WEEKNUM(B3)
Month: =RIGHT(B3,4)&"-"&MID(B3,4,2)
```

I would like to convert the week & month to the following desired format:

```
Week: 2019-1    
2019-01
```

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please tag your question accordingly to attract those who know to your question. (As an aside `2019-01` is ISO 8601 format for *month* 1 of 2019, so how everyone will read it; consider not using that format for *week*  1 of 2019.)

Comment: I am using excel

Comment: I repeat, then please tag your question excel. When you don’t, most people who know Excel won’t notice your question, and your chances of getting a good answer are very small. This time I did it for you, I’m not doing it again.

Comment: How do I tag it once I have posted it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have explained. There’s an Edit tags link beside the tags that are already there (date and format). Just press it and enter more tags. You may also edit your entire question (including the tags) through the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57789837/edit) link that is under the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your excel formulas should look like so:

```
="Week: "&YEAR(B2)&"-"&WEEKNUM(B2)
= YEAR(B2)&"-"&TEXT(MONTH(B3),"MM")
```